# Learning an Email script using Gmail SMTP authentication

Tags: powershell, smtp, gmail, powershell-ise

I'm new to power shell scripting.I wrote a script which should send an email to my inbox

I found few solution and improved my script

```
$cred = Get-Credential
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer "smtp-relay.gmail.com" -Credential $cred -UseSsl -Port 587 -From "test@gmail.com" -To "test@gmail.com" -Subject "test" -Body "test"
```

I got an error message as follows below

```
Send-MailMessage : Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.0 Mail relay denied 
[117.193.79.33]. bd10sm271633igb.4 - gsmtp
At line:2 char:1
+ Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer "smtp-relay.gmail.com" -Credential $cred -UseSsl -P ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-M 
   ailMessage], SmtpException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

Again I changed the port number 465 or 25,it get operation timeout.Help me out!!

PS:Telnet on 25 or 587 is working and no AV program in computer

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you configured Gmail SMTP relay? [Doco](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?hl=en)

Comment: Argh!!You are right,I'm not the enterprise customer.Better I will go off with smtp.gmail.com

Comment: $cred = Get-Credential
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer "smtp.gmail.com" -Credential $cred -UseSsl -Port 587 -From "test@gmail.com" -To "test@gmail.com" -Subject "test" -Body "test" it works after disable two way verification and allow less secure apps in settings https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: Good work, feel free to add that as an answer. You can do that here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$cred = Get-Credential Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer "smtp.gmail.com" -Credential $cred -UseSsl -Port 587 -From "test@gmail.com" -To "test@gmail.com" -Subject "test" -Body "test"

This Testing with Gmail works,after i followed this steps
1.Disable two way verification
2.Allow less secure apps in settings 
[Lesssecure Apps](http://google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)